# How to move to the end of the continuous line by pressing keys in command line in vim editor

Tags: vim

My file contains some content.

```
      This file is just for testing and it may contain no about about any related data. 
      But used for copy of move the content to one file to another.
```

The given line is continuation of the same line. How to move to the cursor to end of the first line by pressing single key.

My _cursor is waiting here

```
      _This file is just for testing and it may contain no about about any related data.
       But used for copy of move the content to one file to another.
```

By pressing singe command or key I need to move to end of first line of my cursor_.

```
      This file is just for testing and it may contain no about about any related data._
       But used for copy of move the content to one file to another.
```

If there is any way, let me know.

Comment: The `vimtutor` command (see `:help vimtutor` inside Vim) provides a good introduction to Vim's capabilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can move to the end of lines in vim using `$` sign. 
   You may use a number in front `$` to move `n` ends down. For instance, `2$` moves to the end of the second line from your cursor.
2. When "wrap" is turned "on", then `g$` moves to the end of SCREEN line. So,
   it differs in functionality from a `$`. For example: If you wanted to move 2 screen lines down use `2g$`, if you wanted to move 2 lines down (when wrap is on) use `2$`.

For more details you can do `:help $` and `:help g$`.